# How to calculate the median count for year / week/ month/day?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, statistics, amazon-redshift

I have some data in table which contains date as one column and count(*).

But I have requirement to draw a chart of median or mean count for that year/month/week/day and the error bar represents the spread of the data

```
SELECT DATE_PART(year,l_date) as year, (count(*))
from am_history
group by year;
```

which gives the year and count of rows per year. How to calculate the median for this count(*) and error (standard deviation)?
I understand if for year i find out the query, the rest for month, week etc can be done easily.

I am new to calculate statistics,Please help

Comment: Could you add the final/expectee result? Thanks.

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using (and use syntax appropriate to that database.  (2) Standard deviation is usually used with the *average* ("mean"), not the median.

Comment: sure, I am using aws redshift. How do we find average value for the count? when i use avg (count(*)) it gives error? @GordonLinoff

Comment: What do you expect to get for "average value for the count"? Are you expecting one row as the result, or one row per year? If you are expecting one row, why are you showing the year? If you are expecting one row per year, what do you mean by the "average count" for the year?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,l_date) as [year], count(l_date) as counts 
from am_history
group by DATEPART(year,l_date);
```

Example:---

```
Declare @tbl Table(
id INT ,
[group]  Varchar(50),
value varchar(50),
Dat DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'1.1.03.01.00.00',NULL,GETUTCDATE()-100)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'1.1.03.01.01.00',NULL,GETUTCDATE() + 7)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'1.1.03.01.02.00',NULL,GETUTCDATE()+10)

SELECT DATEPART(year,Dat)As years,count(Dat) as counts  FROM @tbl  group by DATEPART(year,Dat)
```

Comment: but, how do you find median of this count? and error ( standard dev)??

Comment: This in not a redshift answer.